# Highlight the row that was selected/checked in RadListBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik, radlistbox

I'm using RadListBox with data that coming from the DB, my objective is to highlight the row that was selected in the RadListBox and keep it highlighted until the user changing his selection.

How can I do it???

I gave it a try with jQuery but it didn't work for me.

```
  <div style="border: 0px solid red;padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
                            <telerik:RadListBox ID="rlbNavigateIncidents" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  CheckBoxes="True" ShowCheckAll="False" Width="239px" Height="315px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rlbNavigateIncidents_OnSelectedIndexChanged" OnClientItemChecked="OnClientItemChecked">
                        </telerik:RadListBox>
                        </div>





//============================== //
// Item Checked //
// ============================== //
function pageLoad() {
    $('li.rlbItem > label > input:checked').parent().parent().addClass("rlbSelected");
}


function OnClientItemChecked(sender, args) {
    var el = args.get_item().get_element();
    if (args.get_item().get_checked()) {
        $(el).addClass("rlbSelected");
    }
    else {
        $(el).removeClass("rlbSelected");
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to pre-select a value or is another event on the page causing the list box to rebind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should happen OOB if you bind your listbox only on the initial Page_Load. With this it should not rebind and the controls collection should stay the same, so selection should not change. See this as a basic sample:

```
    <telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="RadListBoxSource" Height="200px" Width="200px"
        AllowTransfer="true" TransferToID="RadListBoxDestination">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Argentina"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Australia"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Brazil"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Canada"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Chile"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="China"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Egypt"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="England"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="France"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Germany"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="India"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Indonesia"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Kenya"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="Mexico"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="New Zealand"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="South Africa"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
            <telerik:RadListBoxItem Text="USA"></telerik:RadListBoxItem>
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadListBox>
    <telerik:RadListBox runat="server" ID="RadListBoxDestination" Height="200px" Width="200px">
    </telerik:RadListBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="postback" runat="server" />
```